# Бельё (не) довешано. Изюм (не) довешен. Вопрос о правописании причастий

Tags: орфография, частица-не, глаголы, причастия, частица

Слитно или раздельно пишется частица с причастиями?

*По поводу (не)довешен.
С одной стороны, глагол недовесить всегда пишется слитно ("Русский язык. Таблицы, схемы, упражнения, 9-е издание, испр. " Долбик, Леонович, Саникович, с.84)
Поэтому причастие недовешен тоже надо писать слитно ("Примечание. Причастия (в полной и краткой формах) и деепричастия, образованные от глаголов с недо-, пишутся тоже слитно" -  "Современная руская орфография" Кайдалова, Калинина, с. 165)
НО: в словаре Ушакова почему-то: 50гр. не довешено (раздельно написано), хотя раздельное написание указывает на значение "не доведенное до конца, прерванное действие", а здесь все-таки, скорее, речь о действии, выполненном ниже нормы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Изюм недовешен, недовешено 50 грамм или не довешено 50 грамм (верны обе формы, в орф. словаре есть глагол "довесить").

НЕДОВЕСИТЬ, -вешу, -весишь; недовешенный; -шен, -а, -о; св. чего. Взвесить, отвесить меньше, чем следует. Н. хлеба, муки, масла. Н. сто граммов сахара.

2) Белье не довешано. В словаре нет глагола "недовешать", но есть глагол "довешать". Например: Вот сейчас довешаю белье и пойду.

Comment: "Не довешено 50 грамм"  означает, что должны были довесить 50 грамм, но не сделали это? Ситуация немного надуманная, не так ли?

Comment: Я очень сомневаюсь в том, что правильно говорить "изюм недовешен", недовешено 50 грамм изюма, а не весь изюм.

Comment: Но в словаре приведен пример: Недовесить сто граммов сахара.  Кстати, величину недовеса люди часто указывают. А ситуации разные бывают. Допустим, развешивают сахар, а потом проверяют: в этом пакете не довешено 50 грамм до нормы.

Comment: Может я неясно выразился: "недовешено сто граммов сахара" -корректно, "сахар недовешен" - некорректно, по-моему.

Comment: "Недовешено 50 граммов" - недостает  50 гр. до нормы. "Не довешено" - значит не сделано довешивание, а это как понимать?

Comment: Пришли на рынок, набрали пакетик черешни. Продавец говорит: "Вам довесить до килограмма?", а вы спрашиваете: "А сколько там не довешено?"

Answer (score 1):

Послушайте, но у Ушакова не изюм, а "пятьдесят гр".

> С одной стороны, глагол недовесить всегда пишется слитно

Утверждение некорректно.

Подразумевается, что это задание на правило: ***"недо" с глаголами пишется слитно.*** Но ведь для понимания и применения этого правила нужен контекст.

Изюм довешивали-довешивали, да не все не довешали. Так остался изюм **не довешен до конца**.

Покупили килограмм изюму. А продавец, нехороший, не довесил 150 грамм. Изюм **недовешан**. Но **не довешено 50 гр. изюма**. *Сейчас бы и этот случай слитно написали, но во времена Ушакова четко было понимание что если 50 гр. (конкретно), то это именно прерванное действие. Взвешивание происходило методом последовательных приближений: перевес - чуть отсыпят, недовес - прибавят. Электронных весов не было, чашечные весы с гирьками.*

Второй вариант очевидно реальнее, но это не гарантия.

Тут еще путаются два значения слова "вешать" - взвешивать и подвешивать, но второе по отношению к изюму маловероятно. Хотя в принципе тоже может сказаться на выборе варианта.

С бельем в принципе-то то же самое. Только его не взвешивают, а подвешивают. 
Но и у белья куда более вероятен вариант "недовешено" - в значении "не вывешено", "не полностью развешено на веревке".

Comment: Интересная интерпретация. Про "довесить".

Comment: Бельё не подвешивают, а развешивают в пространстве. Всё, что в пространстве, пишется с гласным А - вешАть: фотографии развешали по стене, бельё развешали на верёвке, а вот замок повесили вертикально- он повешЕн, товар развесили (что связано с весом - весить)

Comment: @Людмила Бельё не подвешивают, а развешивают в пространстве. -да? Никогда не задумывался. Разве оно не на веревке висит? Да и сомнительно мне кажется насчет пространства. Как-то по-другому нас учили. ладно, вопрос все равно не на это правило.

Comment: ну да... Завешанный - от завешать, завешенный - от завесить. Какое "пространство"? "Висеть" против  "взвешивать" - самодостаточно, нет?.